# Emacs won't enable auto-indent-mode at startup

Tags: init-file

I am trying to set up [`auto-indent-mode`](https://github.com/mlf176f2/auto-indent-mode.el/).

I added it to my init-file like this, but it won't run:

```
(auto-indent-mode)
```

How can I tell Emacs to enable `auto-indent-mode` at startup?

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please have a look at the [EmacsWiki page on `auto-indent-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoIndentMode) to see what it has to say about what to put in your init file.  As a general rule, please try to ask one question at a time -- so ask a separate question about splitting windows if a google search or a search on this site do not provide the answer.

Comment: Asad-ullah Khan: When discussing a third-party library, always provide a link to that library.

Comment: Have a look at the functions `split-window-horizontally` and `split-window-vertically`.  As indicated, you should probably post a new question for your 3-way split with some more details regarding how you want that to work -- e.g., manually, or automatically; if automatically, under what circumstances and how will you determine which buffers should be placed as A, B and C.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, the solution was to use:

`(auto-indent-global-mode)`

Comment: Note that if you use packages that auto-indent whole buffer, it could slow down your Emacs even on a slightly large buffer with over 5000 lines. You will notice a slight delay for every character entered.